Eloquent ORM performance with subqueries for relational models
Laravel eloquent uses subqueries for relationship model instead of joins as joins offer more optimal performance .How does eloquent orm ensures performance for relational models ?

Thats an interesting question and maybe you should ask on github laravel/framework discussions tab

This is a bit vague. Broadly speaking Eloquent does not use subqueries to load related models but it uses an additional query which is "joined" with the first one on the main model id. This is more or less as optimal as a join would be. There are scenarios where eloquent does use subqueries (querying relationship existance for example). Which scenarios specifically are you saying that joins would be more optimal? From my perspective loading related models in a 2nd query is much more optimal, data transfer-wise at least.

Different queries will perform differently when picking between subquery and JOIN.  Please provide one example, but do not infer a general rule.

@apokryfos SQL joins offer optimal performance with indexed columns and also it is using subqueries with in clause for related model Ids

It should not be using subqueries for related model ids. Related models are loaded using a SELECT * FROM related_table WHERE related_id IN (<list of model ids>) where the model ids are hardcoded based on a previous query result. This WHERE IN query should have the same performance as a JOIN on the same column. If you are seeing different queries being made then Please update your question with the Laravel code you run, your table structures and the queries you are seeing as well as some benchmarks of execution times of JOINS compared to the queries you are seeing.

@apokryfos Thanks but my objective was that joins can avail benefits of indexing strategy and hence it can offer more optimal performance as compared to subqueries

If I understand correctly, this happens only checking the existence of a relation using the exists/not exists (e.g. whereHas, orWhereHas.)
select * from table t where exists (select id from relation where parent_id = t.id)

The above does not need to care about the values of the matching rows in relation, only that they exist.
